# how to format date elasticsearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

1.my search Query

```
var searchResults = await client.SearchAsync<CDPDocument>(i => i
                             .Index(indexname)
                             .From(0)
                             .Size(1)
                             .Query(q => q
                                  .Bool(b => b
                                      .Must(
                                          bs => bs.Exists(p => p.Field("demoinfos"))
                                      )            
                                )
                              )
                          );
```

2. my class

```
    public class CDPDocument
    {
        [Text(Index = true)]
        public string phone { get; set; }
        [Boolean(Index = true)]
        public bool is_active { get; set; }
        [Date]
        public DateTime updatedate{ get; set; }
    }
```

3. invalid datetime format. value:2021-10-23 08:55:37

because elasticsearch data is "updatedate" : "2021-10-21 20:43:46"

this is Exception :

Exception: InvalidOperationException Took: 00:00:00.1149820

## Audit exception in step 3 BadResponse:

System.InvalidOperationException: invalid datetime format. value:2021-10-23 08:55:37
at Elasticsearch.Net.Utf8Json.Formatters.ISO8601DateTimeFormatter.Deserialize(JsonReader& reader, IJsonFormatterResolver formatterResolver)

Comment: `Nest` client uses `ISO8601DateTimeFormatter` for `DateTime` deserialization. The data in your case for the `DateTime` field doesn't appear to be in the expected `ISO8601` format.